# TV show that starts with debris encompassing Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

Someone recently recommended a TV show to me. I remember them saying it starts with aliens coming to Earth, because something happened to their planet and they are in need of help. They agree to be settled or integrated somewhere, and then mysteriously the ship they had come in blows up. It leaves so much debris around the Earth that people/aliens can no longer go into space. I think he also said that the aliens have the ability to terraform.

Does anyone know what show this is/was?

Comment: It's a movie as opposed to a TV show, but strangely enough this element was also incorporated in the opening of WALL-E.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like [Defiance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2189221/):

> aliens known collectively as Votans have come to Earth seeking a new
>   home after their solar system was destroyed. However, when they
>   reached Earth, they discovered despite a prolonged negotiation with
>   the government on Earth, they were not welcome. Rather than turn away,
>   they began a war with the humans as they are determined to make Earth
>   their new home. During the war, the Votans dropped terraformers on the
>   planet and transformed the surface; scorching the earth, opening
>   chasms in the ground and covering the surface of the planet in dust
>   and debris.

Comment: Ninja!  Beat me by *that* much...

Comment: Yes this is it! thank you

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like Defiance, which ran three seasons on SyFy.  There had been a war of invasion, which Earth was losing, before the disaster that destroyed one or more of the alien colony ships.  After peace was made, there were (IIRC) four alien races living among humans on an Earth that had been partially "fast terraformed" to an alien planet's environment.  The show was set in what was left of St. Louis, with a radio station that broadcast from high up one leg of the broken Arch, and one of the powerful Human families made their living owning and running a mine that recovered old technology and materials from the buried city.

The protagonist is a Human soldier from the war, who adopted an alien child just after the peace was made.  The child is now grown, and he returns to Defiance, the place built on top of St. Louis, where the war came to an end because one side refused to kill the others.  One of the first season episodes included what the characters called "steel rain" -- falling debris fragments from the destruction of ships in Earth orbit.

The plots of most episodes revolve around the interactions between humans and characters of the other races -- a sort of "alien Mafia Don" along with his wife and son, the town doctor, and others I've forgotten, dealing with the daughter of the mine owner, the former soldier (who was elected sheriff), and various others.